# Prevent double wrapping of a javascript function

Tags: javascript

I have the following function, which receives another function signature, and an object as a parameter, and creates a new function, which when invoked, will call the input function adding the input object as a parameter to it:

```js
function wrapFunction(inputFunction, inputObject) {
    return function() {
        const originalParameters = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);

        originalParameters.unshift(inputObject);
        return inputFunction.apply(this, originalParameters);
    }
}
```

Now, if I run the following javascript:

```js
let myFunction = function() {
    console.log('dummy');
}

myFunction = wrapFunction(myFunction, inputObject);
myFunction = wrapFunction(myFunction, inputObject);
```

the final myFunction signature should look something like this: `myFunction(inputObject, inputObject)`.

Is there any way I can find out in `wrapFunction` if the `inputFunction` is a function on which `wrapFunction` was already used or not to prevent double wrapping it?

On the same example as above, my expected result would be, that the final `myFunction` signature should look like this: `myFunction(inputObject)`

Comment: _"the final myFunction signature should look something like this: `myFunction(inputObject, inputObject)`"_ vs. _"the final myFunction signature should look like this: `myFunction(inputObject)`"_ ?

Comment: "*to prevent double wrapping it*" why do you want to avoid that? Since wrapping the function just adds a parameter to the beginning, it seems perfectly logical to me to allow wrapping twice to add two parameters in the beginning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One idea could be to add a marker on the function:

```js
const marker = new Symbol();

function wrapFunction(inputFunction, inputObject) {
    if (inputFunction[market]) return inputFunction;
    const r = function() {
        const originalParameters = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);

        originalParameters.unshift(inputObject);
        return inputFunction.apply(this, originalParameters);
    }
    r[marker] = true;
    return r;
}
```